# Is there a complete win32 wrapper library?

Tags: winapi, opengl, openglcontext

I search a win32 wrapper libraray that completly isolate me from the api.
I only want to create a opengl 3.3 window for windows only.
I know there are libraries like GLFW, SFML and SDL but this libraries are to large and heavy.
Know someone one?

Comment: try GLEW http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @user2485710: GLEW doesn't create windows.

Comment: What's heavy about GLFW? It won't get any more minimalistic than that.

Comment: @datenwolf: I guess you could completely forgo input handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could suggest you to use Qt library, but you would also complain because of the size of the dlls.

I'm afraid you won't find easily such lightweight library.

Using Win32 SDK for creating an OpenGL application is not that difficult. As for an experienced Win32 developer, I insist that it's even really easy.
It's always the same program structure, same messages handled, same function calls (loop, threads etc).

Please have a look on the internet for the OpenLG SuperBible tutorials.

[OpenGL SuperBible Examples](http://www.openglsuperbible.com/example-code/)

Z.